# Faster building of Kafka Streams state

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have default 7 days of latest streaming data stored in Kafka:

`log.retention.hours=168`

When deploying new version of Streams application, it takes significant amount of time to process the old data before being able to actually use it.

Are there any options to make it quicker other than reducing the retention period?

What comes to my mind is that state stores shouldn't be persisted to disk until all data is processed.

Comment: Retention is for non compact topics. State stores are stored in compacted topics, and can remain indefinitely, and so, yes, it'll take a long time to read them, and there's not really a good way around that

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have state-stores with changelog topics in your app, and the thing that takes time is restoring the state of the app?

1. Even if the input topic has retention set, changelog topics have [cleanup.policy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#topicconfigs_cleanup.policy) set to compact by default, so unlimited retention.
2. What is the size of the keyset? A changelog topic consist of the number of keys you store, you can try reducing this to get a smaller state.
3. Consider changing the [segment.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#topicconfigs_segment.ms) and [min.cleanable.dirty.ratio](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#topicconfigs_min.cleanable.dirty.ratio) to optimize for compacting.
4. Consider tuning [rocksDB config](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-tune-rocksdb-kafka-streams-state-stores-performance/)

Comment: No changelog, just regular state store (only the last value should be saved AFAIK).

Comment: By default every statestore is backed up by a changelog in kafka-streams. That's how it is able to rebuild the statestore when the app is restarted.
You can disable the changelog using [Materialized.withLoggingDisabled()](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html#withLoggingDisabled()), but then you would lose the state upon restart.

Comment: Ok so the ideal solution for us would be to configure Streams API to only process latest 24 hours of data while keeping default 7 days of data in original topics. But this is not an option it seems.

Comment: There are ways to do this. You should read and understand [this article](https://objectpartners.com/2019/07/31/slimming-down-your-kafka-streams-data/).

Comment: Ok so I can add `transform()` operation in the beginning of processing and return *null* for records older than specific timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally came up with is processing only last N hours of original data in my Streams application using **filter**:

```
myStream.filter({ (_, value) =>
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -streamHours)

        value.timestamp > calendar.getTimeInMillis
      })
```